# How to make IntelliJ recognize multiple application properties as being Spring configurations?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, properties

I have been moving around my 'application.properties' file provided by Spring Boot and creating copies in other folders to compare precedence by location.

I noticed that the file lost the icon [image] meaning it was recognized by IntelliJ as a Spring configuration file.
The file [image]still works fine, but all the spring property references now say: "unused property".

I know some other Questions similar to this solve the "unused property"-message by ignoring them entirely, but then you lose the Spring configuration hinting too.

Isn't there some way to have IntelliJ recognize the file as being Spring configurations again?

I have tried to:

- Invalidate cache and restart
- Inject languages and references
- Look in project structure to add the files again somehow
- Delete all generated files and rebuild project from POM

But I haven't found the light yet... Anyone knows how I would go about doing this? It would be nice to be able to mark multiple files, so all the application.proprties files I use will hint at the options for spring configuration.

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: That doesn't help, I tried that too, I'll add it to things I tried ...

Comment: What edition do you use - Ultimate or Community? Is it possible to share sample project example?

Comment: Ultimate. I received an answer from JetBrains. I re-wrote their answer here for people to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently IntelliJ IDEA fails to recognize application.properties if you have several properties-files currently.

A bug report has been created:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-255946

(As a workaround, you need to retain only one application.properties in your resource folder and then reopen this project.)

Comment: You might want to add a link to the bug in this answer, so that people can vote on the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Try: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html#custom-configuration-files (Custom configuration files)

Comment: That's the 3d option I tried. I can add the .properties but they do not convert to 'valid' spring configuration by themselves. This doesn't fix the hinting either. Unless I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after creating a new module in my project and adding an `application.properties` to the resource folder. It was shown with the wrong icon and when I started the app, the config was also not used.

It seemed that the spring context was not properly loaded. I noticed that Intellij showed a warning in the SpringBoot application class (the class name was marked yellow). Clicking `ALT + Enter` on it and choosing the first option *Create SpringBoot facet* solved the issue. You will see the project structure dialog and only need to click OK.

Comment: I had three properties files and they all worked, IntelliJ just didn't like that I had 3... It was a bug (or just not supported). I contacted JetBrains, and that is what they told me. So I just had to deal working without intellisense.